# Configuring home network that uses 2 hubs/routers

Tags: lan, wan

I have two computers (one Win7 and one XP) upstairs networked via a Netgear hub/router. File and printer sharing works fine.

The Netgear hub/router is connected to another hub/router supplied by my ISP (Virgin media) downstairs, which in turn connects to the internet.

I'd like to connect another (Win 7) computer directly to the hub/router downstairs. But I'm pretty certain that configuring file/printer sharing the other PCs won't be as simple as when they are connected through the same hub. I have some idea how I could connect to it through the internet, but this doesn't seem like a very sensible solution.

Can anyone suggest how I would go about this? I don't have much (in fact hardly any) networking experience. So I'm not even sure whether I'd be setting up a LAN, WAN or what it would be.

If I followed the instructions [here](http://routersetup.blogspot.co.uk/2007/08/connecting-two-routers-wired.html) would that allow me to just configure all PCs with an IP 192.168.1.x just as if they were all on the same hub?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment are both routers functioning as routers?

You need to setup a single LAN, this isn't so difficult and there is a good chance this is already how your network is setup.

Can you show the output of 'ipconfig', in the command prompt window whilst connected to both the upstairs router and your Virgin Superhub.

If you are on a single subnet of the LAN, then you will have no problems sharing as regardless of the extra 'router' you are still on the same network.

The second router should not be acting as a router in such a simple network but rather a switch, this means that it simply directs traffic to the Virgin Superhub router.

This can be done one of two ways, either by not using the WAN or Internet port on the second router, or disabling router functions on the router such as DHCP.

Comment: I'll be adding the third computer at the weekend. So at the moment I'm just trying to anticipate any problems I'm likely to encounter, as my internet connection (and therefore any advice I could get) is likely to be affected when I start making changes. Judging by your post and the link I posted, it looks as though it might work just by disabling DHCP on the upstairs router and chnging the ethernet port connecting the two routers. I'll update this in a couple of days with the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I have on many occasions actually left DHCP on, not altered a router in any way what so ever but used the LAN ports on a router and avoided using the WAN port with great success. This doesn't always work but I've only ever had it fail once on an old Apple Airport Express router.

Answer (score 0):

Virgin (cable) router/gateways (aka superhubs) have two basic modes of operation. They can act as a normal router/gateway (routing internal local area traffic through to the wider internet, provide IP addresses to your local machines - DHCP - firewalling, and so on).  They also have a pass-through mode where they pass the external connection straight through to an ethernet WAN port on an alternative router/gateway.  This allows the alternative router/gateway to handle the normal router/gateway operations.  In this mode only one of the ethernet ports on the rear of the superhub is active (in my set-up it's the one nearest the Cable input - in your case it may be different as you may have a different superhub).

(What Netgear hub/router do you have?  Does it have a WAN port?)

The set-up you have described is typical for a situation where Virgin has been installed into an already working set-up as part of an ISP change.  It involves minimal disruption and allows you to continue to use the features of the existing router/gateway (it's the way I'd do it). On the other hand, Virgin engineers don't normally set the superhub to pass-through mode as part of their install routine. However, it's worth checking because if the superhub *is* in pass-through mode the remaining ports won't work (and your downstairs machine won't see the internet if it's plugged in there).  It's easily checked.  The Virgin icon on the front will be purple if it is in pass-through mode.

If the superhub *isn't* in pass-through mode and your network is stable, then adding the downstairs machine should simple be a case of plugging it in (as long as it's configured to get an IP address via DHCP).

Utilising the Homegroup feature of Windows should help simplify the sharing of resources.

One final thought.  If you can, ditch the XP operating system and install something like Ubuntu instead.  Now XP is no longer being patched by MS it's becoming increasingly vulnerable. If you really can't ditch it than make sure that it's properly firewalled, check the firewall on the superhub, make sure you have updated anti-virus, etc, etc.